# UTF8 not working no PHP apache Mac

Tags: php, macos, utf-8

My app is receiving a query from client in form of a POST request.

Chrome 34 will send the POST request (RAW): `val=%C2%A9`

When I look at $_POST['val'] via xdebug or error_log($_POST['val']) I see `?`.

Website is utf8 encoded. PHP is set to work in utf8:

`mb_internal_encoding() -> UTF-8`

`default_chatset = utf-8`

This problem occurs on my Mac 10.9 dev machine. Our Ubuntu production server with same php and apache settings converts POST to the utf8 string. Is there any "other" internal encoding that PHP would work in that it possibly inherits from the sysytem it is working on?

Comment: `val%5D` implies that the parameter name is `'val]'`.

Comment: Sorry, trimmed too much. Corrected

Comment: What are you trimming?  Perhaps that's relevant.  Better to show what's actually there rather than trimming things to make it easier on us!

Comment: Here is full POST request from client: `data%5Bpxid%5D=im_681&data%5Bxid%5D=im_682&data%5Bfield%5D=cNam&data%5Bval%5D=a&data%5Breq_id%5D=1398350952236&action=updEdible`

Comment: That doesn't contain `val=%C2%A9` (nor anything even slightly close: I can't see *any* non-ASCII data there).  It *does* contain `data%5Bval%5D=a`, which will result in `$_POST['data']['val']` containing the string `'a'`, but I'm not sure how that relates to your problem?

Comment: The character in question is the [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) after the character 'a'. It's possible on OS X that xdebug itself is not set up to display UTF-8. I also know that the Terminal on OS X has trouble displaying Unicode characters sometimes. How are you viewing xdebug and your error logs?